# error with iis while returning large size string through webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis, iis-5

I  want to return a image through webservice , so i tried to convert the image in database to byte then from byte to base64 string and return it to webservice , i am done with half the way but i could not return the whole string hope due to some restriction of string size or something else ?

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="Service" %>


using System;

using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;

using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.IO;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public Service () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string IMAGE(string ID)
    {


        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=NEWCRISP19;Initial Catalog=masselango;Persist Security Info=True;User");
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sdImageSource = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sdImageSource.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select ImageData from ImagesStore where ImageId=('" + ID + "')", conn);
        DataSet dsImage = new DataSet();
        sdImageSource.Fill(dsImage);

        byte[] blob = (byte[])dsImage.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];
        String c = Convert.ToBase64String(blob);
        //c = c.Replace(" ", "");
        return c;


    }

}
```

The web.config is unmodified.

help me retrieveing the whole base64 string .

Comment: Can you not pass it back as a byte array?

Comment: Though I need to pass as base64 string for my application process i used transfering as such , though it returns some limit of characters to pass and it does'nt pass whole data

Comment: I'm not aware of a restriction on the length of a sting via webservices (but am happy to be told otherwise), but if you're seeing a problem then I don't see what is stopping you passing the byte array and then converting to the base64 sting *in* the client application

Comment: I would use a DataReader rather than DataSet.   Check the web server if it has any limitations.   See if you can convert back to blob and display on the server to be sure it is transmission problem.

Comment: hey guys i found out the problem, it could return the string exactly when its executed out of iis , when i run through the iis it doent returns the exact string

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use the legacy ASMX web services instead of WCF? They're not meant to be used for new development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i understood is you have stored image in database as binary and you want to retrieve it now.


If that is you want then please check this Link [Insertion and Retrieval of image in binary](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/01/how-to-insert-images-into-database-and.html)

Comment: OP is asking about webservices, looks like they have the database side of things sorted